# Eclipse+PyDev+GAE memcache "Undefined variable from import: get"

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

I've started using Eclipe+PyDev as an environment for developing my first app for Google App Engine. Eclipse is configured according to [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/eclipse.html).

Everything was working until I start to use memcache. PyDev reports the errors and I don't know how to fix it:

[image]

Error: Undefined variable from import: get

How to fix this?
Sure, it is only PyDev checker problem. Code is correct and run on GAE.

UPDATE:

1. I'm using PyDev 1.5.0 but experienced the same with 1.4.8.
2. My PYTHONPATH includes (set in Project Properties/PyDev - PYTHONPATH):

   - `C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine`
   - `C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django`
   - `C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webob`
   - `C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml\lib`

UPDATE 2:

I took a look at `C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\memcache\__init__.py` and found `get()` is not declared as `memcache` module function. They use the following trick to do that (I didn't hear about such possibility):

```
_CLIENT = None


def setup_client(client_obj):
  """Sets the Client object instance to use for all module-level methods.

  Use this method if you want to have customer persistent_id() or
  persistent_load() functions associated with your client.

  Args:
    client_obj: Instance of the memcache.Client object.
  """
  global _CLIENT
  var_dict = globals()

  _CLIENT = client_obj
  var_dict['set_servers'] = _CLIENT.set_servers
  var_dict['disconnect_all'] = _CLIENT.disconnect_all
  var_dict['forget_dead_hosts'] = _CLIENT.forget_dead_hosts
  var_dict['debuglog'] = _CLIENT.debuglog
  var_dict['get'] = _CLIENT.get
  var_dict['get_multi'] = _CLIENT.get_multi
  var_dict['set'] = _CLIENT.set
  var_dict['set_multi'] = _CLIENT.set_multi
  var_dict['add'] = _CLIENT.add
  var_dict['add_multi'] = _CLIENT.add_multi
  var_dict['replace'] = _CLIENT.replace
  var_dict['replace_multi'] = _CLIENT.replace_multi
  var_dict['delete'] = _CLIENT.delete
  var_dict['delete_multi'] = _CLIENT.delete_multi
  var_dict['incr'] = _CLIENT.incr
  var_dict['decr'] = _CLIENT.decr
  var_dict['flush_all'] = _CLIENT.flush_all
  var_dict['get_stats'] = _CLIENT.get_stats


setup_client(Client())
```

Hmm... Any idea how to force PyDev to recognize that?

Comment: Same with 1.4.8? So it should be a PYTHONPATH definition problem then.

Comment: I still got this error with Eclipse Indigo SR2 + PyDev 2.5 (Google App Engine 1.6.6 app) and Python 3.2. weird thing... The solution in my case was to add `#@PydevCodeAnalysisIgnore` at the top of the page as @Richard Green mentions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2930265/114029

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of PyDev are you using? A recent one (1.5) or the old one referred by the Google tutorial?
See [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/forums/forum/293649/topic/3388818).

There is a similar [issue with PyROOT](http://root.cern.ch/root/roottalk/roottalk09/0064.html)

> Since PyDEV plugin does not read `$HOME/.pystartup`, touching functions/ classes is not a solution. Because it analyze the syntax and structures of python modules to be imported not on-the-fly but when I set the `PYTHONPATH` from Eclipse's preference panel.

So does your `PYTHONPATH` reference the Google library?

---

They might be an issue with code completion in 1.5 which could force you to disable code analysis: [Pydev 1.5.0 code anlaysis breaks code pyqt4 code completion - ID: 2855598](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2855598&group_id=85796&atid=577329)

> have `pyqt 4.5.4` installed.
>   Initially I had `pydev 1.4.8` the open source version installed and code completion worked fine.
>   After updating to pydev 1.5.0, pyqt code completion stopped functioning.
>   After disabling the Pydev code analysis in **`"eclipse preferences -> pydev -> editor -> code analysis -> do code analysis?"`**, code completion began working again for PyQt
>   classes etc.

Comment: I'm using PyDev 1.5.0 but experienced the same with 1.4.8.

Answer (score 25):

There is a cleaner solution: Try adding GAE's memcache to your forced builtins.

In your PyDev->Interpreter-Python->ForcedBuiltins window, add the "google.appengine.api.memcache" entry and apply.

Double-click on the memcache errors to check them back, they disappear!

Please make sure that system pythonpath includes google APE install directory.

Comment: Not sure why but I had to remove the project from the eclipse and re-import it for this to work.

Comment: this worked for me in OS X Lion with Indigo and with the latest PyDev 2.5+ and GAE 1.6.6 _after_ I removed and re-imported the GAE project as @Ralphz said...to add your Google App Engine folder in OS X, [you will need to go into the .app folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888107/how-do-i-select-a-file-within-a-app-in-mac-os-x)...

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late to the party, but you can add the following comment in all of your files that use memcache to selectively switch off pydev analysis:

`#@PydevCodeAnalysisIgnore`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to turn off all code analysis for your project/module, then just turn it off for that line. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112715/how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors/2248987#2248987) explains that you can hit Ctrl+1 to bring up quick fix and insert `#@UndefinedVariable` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me and it's different than the solutions above.
Pretty straight forward:
http://blog.kicaj.com/fixing-pydev-memcache-unresolved-import/

Just says to add the google_appengine folder to the pydev python interpreter library.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that by adding this few lines to my code on the top of my file:

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache
# work-around for Eclipse+PyDev+GAE memcache error
if not hasattr(memcache, 'set'):
    Client=None
    memcache.setup_client(Client)
    memcache = Client
```

You can commnet it out in production version.

It's only to keep eclipse happy and to let code completion work.