# How do I select a file within a .app in Mac OS X?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, macos, pydev

I'm trying to configure PyDev in eclipse, and as part of that I'm trying to add some source folders to the External Libraries section for PYTHONPATH. However, when I click "Add source folder" in eclipse, it's not letting me drill into any .app directories. Normally, in regular Finder, I would right click and choose "Show Package Contents", but through the "Add Source Folder" in Eclipse, all the .apps are greyed out and I can't right click on them. Any ideas on how I get past this? Specifically, I'm looking to drill into the GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app. I'm still very new to Macs, so I'm guessing (hoping?) the solution is easy and obvious to one of you out there.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.app's are just directories and you can treat them as such. If you can manually type the path, i think that would work (it does with other programs I've used).

As for drilling into the package from the file dialog, it may be possible, but I haven't found how.

Just checked this & it worked for me (you'll have to manually type the full path in the popup):

```
The "Go To Folder…" keyboard shortcut (⌘⇧G) works from within "Open" or "Save"
dialogues    and should allow access to the interior of packages by entering
a path...
```

This shortcut works anywhere from finder, useful for getting to those hidden folders such as /etc & /usr

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see a place to manually type the path. There is just the "Add Source Folder" button which then launches the file dialog.

Comment: Ordinarily, I just upvote when I find something obscure like this. But it really deserves comment. Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When Eclipse brings up the file-open dialog, switch over to the Mac Finder, browse to the .app, drill down into it with right-click > Show Package Contents, and then drag the file or folder you want from the Finder window onto the file-open dialog that Eclipse is still showing.