# Undefined variable from import when using wxPython in pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, wxpython, pydev

I just downloaded wxPython, and was running some of the sample programs from [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#First_steps). However, on every line that uses a variable from wx.*, I get a "Undefined variable from import error"

For example, the following program generates five errors on lines 1,4,8, and two on line 5:

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """ We simply derive a new class of Frame. """
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.Show(True)
app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, 'Small editor')
app.MainLoop()
```

The program, however, compiles and runs perfectly. I haven't made any significant modifications to pydev or eclipse, and the wxPython install is fresh.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Is any solution for this problem available besides waiting for the devolpers to fix it?

Comment: I had the same problem and it went away when I updated to PyDev 1.5.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the newer versions of pydev ***(circa January 2010)*** have a hard time tracking down imported names. It's probably nothing.

If this is *still* occurring, report the bug to <strike>aptana</strike> [appcelerator](http://pydev.org/), though no doubt they already know about it.

I get this problem when working with packages I've just recently downloaded, and eventually the errors go away. My most recent problem was after downloading pygame ***(circa January 2010)***.

**Edit**

I've amended my answer above since people are downvoting it, and I'm assuming it's because the information is stale, or because appcelerator bought aptana. I have not used pydev with Eclipse for nearly 2 years and the situation may be different now.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug, although it may have been in January.  See my answer below.

Comment: With pydev 1.5.6.2010033101, today I still had the import error when trying to include networkx for the first time. The procedure you mentioned in your answer is what I have been using since Jan 2010 to overcome the issue. Occasionally simply restarting Eclipse has been enough (e.g. with pygame back in Jan 2010), though the interpreter remove/add works every time.

Comment: Also, I think I remember reading somewhere on the aptana site a recommendation to use the remove/add method you listed below as a solution.

Answer (score 40):

This happened to me.  I had installed PyDev and configured it and went on my merry way.  A few months later, I installed wxPython and had this same problem.  An easy way to fix is in eclipse:

Window -> Preferences -> Pydev -> Interpreter - Python

Just remove the default interpreter and add a new one (it can be the same one you had before).  Pydev/Eclipse searches through your Python Installation directory and adds the correct paths to your PYTHONPATH.  I restarted and all was well.  I noticed it added

```
C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
```

So you could probably just add that to the PYTHONPATH instead of going through all the above, assuming that path is where this directory is installed.

By the way, I am using:

1. Eclipse Helios
2. Pydev 1.6.2.2010090812
3. Python 2.6
4. wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.11.0-py26

But I think this should be a pretty general solution to the problem.

Comment: Cheers! Note for OsX: the wxpython installer apparently puts wxpython in a different location -- after adding "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.11.0/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode" it worked for me

Comment: Works, but on my system the problem re-appears when I start working on the project a few days later. The "from    wx import wx #@UnresolvedImport" solution by 'N3nn' works best.

Answer (score 7):

PyDev finds the references when you setup the interpreter in

> ```
> Window -> Preferences -> Pydev -> Interpreter - Python
> ```

If wxPython was not in your site-packages directory when you first setup the interpreter, then the references to the wx objects and names will not be known to the editor lookup function.  To fix this, remove the interpreter from

> ```
> Window -> Preferences -> Pydev -> Interpreter - Python
> ```

and then select new.  Re-add the python installation again and press apply.  At this time, Pydev will import all of the site-package objects again and should populate the lookup dictionary.  You'll want to restart Eclipse for changes to take place.

Answer (score 3):

Use `CTRL+1` key combination on error text and add `#@UndefinedVariable` or `#@UnresolvedImport` in the end of corresponding lines with errors, it will remove these warnings temporary. See this answer: [How do I fix PyDev "Undefined variable from import" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112715/how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors#answer-2248987)

Answer (score 3):

Try

wx = wx

Don't ask why. This approach (that I found when trying to break the problem in smaller parts) just seems to remove the wx undefined variables problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
#import  wx 
from    wx import wx #@UnresolvedImport
```

will fix.