# Why is Pydev in Eclipse claiming errors on a working program?

Tags: python, eclipse, tkinter, pydev

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse PyDev now shows all references to Tkinter as errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946080/eclipse-pydev-now-shows-all-references-to-tkinter-as-errors)

I have the very simple test project:

```
from Tkinter import *

win = Tk()
l = Label(win, text="Hello, TKInter")
l.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

It runs fine, but in Eclipse, I get the following two errors:

```
Undefined variable: Label line 3
Undefined variable: Tk line 2
```

Am I doing something to generate these errors? If not, is there a way to force Eclipse to re-evaluate those lines correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you `import *`. Eclipse hence don't know that Tk and Label is imported. Use `from Tkinter import Tk, Label` instead.

Comment: ... [which is better anyway](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import).