# How to remove error "error" mark in Eclipse Pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Environment: Windows 7 (Python 2.7)

Here is the problem:
[image]

The weird thing is, this script could run normally. I just want to remove the annoying error mark.

Answer (score 0):

I found similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112715/how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143549/undefined-variable-from-import-when-using-wxpython-in-pydev/3743861#3743861).
After combine several answers given, Eclipse works fine now:

1. [changed the name of the folder 'Lib' to 'lib' (C:\Python27\lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7240776/1035859)
2. In Window -> Preferences -> Pydev -> Interpreter - Python, add PIL folder in PYTHONPATH. Click `Apply`, `OK`, restart Eclipse... The world is beautiful again