# PyDev does not highlight and autocomplete Numpy correctly

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pydev

I am using a mac, I set up all the external libraries through PYTHONPATH, I tried setting it through Pydev interpreter as well.

It simply does not work. The odd thing is that pydev is highlighting the syntax as error, but when I run the code, it works perfectly. I am out of ideas of what the problem might be. I used to program in java with eclipse, and once you set up the external libraries all the highlighting and autocompletion is working. With pydev I have no idea what  is wrong.

Here is the image of the wrong highlighting:

[image: picture showing error]

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar problem with importing wxPython with PyDev Aptana Studio 3. Based on the research I did then, PyDev has a hard time validating new imports when a module has recently been downloaded. This means that there is just a bug in PyDev, so it would be a good idea to report it.

As for the solution, from what I've found a useful link with a ton of answers that should fix your problem. There's some detailed instructions but the fix that I found was towards the bottom someone said to try `wx = wx` after importing wx. This worked for me, but may not work for you so here is the link if you need a better answer:

[Undefined variable from import when using wxPython in pydev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143549/undefined-variable-from-import-when-using-wxpython-in-pydev/2143555#2143555)

Comment: @semrap - wx = wx worked partially. I still when i use import xxx as wx. But otherwise I still have the same problem.

Thanks!