# Pydev say, "Unresolved import" error

Tags: pydev

hm..
Sometime, PyDev say "Unresolved import error".
In my environment

> Python2.6.6 Eclipse3.7 PyDev2.2.2

Errors are.

```
> Unresolved import: pycassa  -> import pycassa Unresolved import:
> WebSocketHandler  -> from geventwebsocket.handler import
> WebSocketHandler Unresolved import: tweepy  -> import tweepy
```

Is there any helpfull information?

Comment: A duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631377/unresolved-import-issues-with-pydev-and-eclipse  -  try to "Remove PyDev Project Config" (Right click on Project -> PyDev)

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem.  In the end I was able to fix the problem by deleting my old interpreter in Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters, and creating a new interpreter called "python" which had the correct paths.  After quitting and reopening eclipse, pydev found all my modules.

Answer (score 4):

Probably your PYTHONPATH is not set properly (or if those are libraries in the interpreter, maybe you added them after configuring it).

See: http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html for references (note the part on forced builtins there as it might be your case).

Comment: For {pyodbc} adding it to the list of forced builtins fixed this issue for me.  Adding pyodbc's egg-info folder to the PYTHONPATH did not.

Answer (score 2):

You get an unresolved import if the required module cannot be found. Modules are searched for in the current working directory and the directories listed in sys.path. Your python cannot find the modules pycassa and tweepy it appears.

Might want to check this: http://klaith.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/pydev-unresolved-import-errors/

Comment: hhm, But I can run myscript normally. Problem is only for "PyDev". I can run that script and , I can import such module via using "IDLE"

Answer (score 2):

I solved by recreate the interpreter. There is a guide at [pedev.org](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html):

> What if I add something new in my System PYTHONPATH after configuring
>   it?
>
> If you add something to your python installation, you need to either
>   add it manually as a 'new folder' in the System PYTHONPATH (if it's
>   still not under a folder in the PYTHONPATH) or (recommended) remove
>   your interpreter and add it again, then, press apply.
>
> Note that if you added a library that's already under a folder in the
>   PYTHONPATH, you have to at least go to the interpreter preferences and
>   press apply so that it clears its internal caches (after the
>   configuration is done, things are set in stone for PyDev)

Thanks for Fabio **Zadrozny** and **nicodjimenez**.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before. I solved the problem by this steps:

1)Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreter

2)Delete the Python Interpreter path you added previously

3)Add "New" Python Interpreter and choose python.exe path

4)Check Libraries tab (I found the problem at this step.)
Check your path name, is it true or false? Eclipse detect "C:\Python27\lib" but it should be "C:\Python27\libs" and "C:\Python27\Lib".

[image: Check and add true path]

[image: File path]

Answer (score 1):

In the properties for your pydev project, there's a pane called "PyDev - PYTHONPATH", with a sub-pane called "External Libraries". You can add source folders (any folder that has an **init**.py) to the path using that pane. Your project code will then be able to import modules from those source folders.
Check this two links it may be helps to you,
[Unresolved Import Issues with PyDev and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631377/unresolved-import-issues-with-pydev-and-eclipse)

[Unresolved import: models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983088/unresolved-import-models)

Comment: Yes, this seems to work, thanks. But this absolutely should NOT be necessary for the issue I have: namely an import for a sibling .py file (i.e. same directory) showing the yellow triangle "UnresolvedImport". Eclipse should not flag any problem at all with an import of a sibling .py file! Annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Is pycassa found as a symlink within a directory on your PYTHONPATH? Pydev apparently has a bug where its code analysis cannot follow symlinks (and hence will not see your libraries). The python interpreter can though of course.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with the dbfpy module.

1. I had downloaded the tar archive and installed the source files in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
2. With this I was able to import the packages in IDLE and even run the code in Eclipse. However the pydev import was still showing as an error with the message "unresolved import"
3. As suggested by Fabio, I checked the PyDev documentation for forced-builtins. Just adding the name of the package ("dbfpy" in my case to the Forced Builtit tab of Python Interpretr in Eclipse) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

(I know the answer is a bit late)
if you installed a python package using, for example: pip install django
i solved the unresolved import issue doing this:
In eclipse:
Window > Preferences
In the left panel tree structure go to:
PyDev > Interpreter - Python 
In the upper right panel be sure to have the correct interpreted selected
and in the bottom right panel, click New Folder, navigate to your python installation site-packages (usually in c:\Python33\Lib\site-packages) and search for a folder that ends with .egg-info
In my pc it is "C:\Apps\Environments\Python33\Lib\site-packages\Django-1.5.4-py3.3.egg-info" since i installed python in C:\Apps\Environments, should be different in your case.
This worked with django and selenium, should work with all others as well (as far as i know)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the corresponding package folder ending with '.egg-info' to PyDev > Interpreter - Python - library will resolve the problem.

In Linux, it is usually under /usr/local/lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages

Answer (score 0):

Add site-packages path in environmental variables.

Right click on

> computer -> properties -> advanced system settings -> Environmental
>   variables

.

After that is done, remove the python interpreter and add it again in eclipse.
right click project name in

> eclipse --> properties --> python interpreter

.

Hope it works.