# tweepy "undefined variable" errors

Tags: python, aptana, tweepy

I am new to both python and Aptana.

I am trying to use the tweepy package in python. I have the following code (from [python's site](http://packages.python.org/tweepy/html/getting_started.html)):

```
import tweepy

user = tweepy.api.get_user('twitter') # "undefined variable" error occurs on this line
print user.screen_name
print user.followers_count
for friend in user.friends():
    print friend.screen_name
```

I get an "Undefined variable from import: get_user". The code actually runs fine with no errors and produces the expected results. I googled and [found](http://mitchfournier.com/2010/06/18/aptana-studio-and-undefined-variable-from-import-doesnotexist/) how to resolve the undefined variable error, but it seems like a hack-a-round. In sum, that link says to add "get_user" to globals in the preferences.

Being new to both Python and Aptana, I just wanted to check to see if that is the *best* way to resolve it....it just seems like a hack. When I change "tweepy.api.get_user" to "tweepy.api.public_timeline" I get the same error and thus will have to manually add "public_timeline" to the globals....It doesn't seem like the correct way when you have to manually configure each variable.

thanks!

Comment: @DSM Reading between the lines a little, I think it's a bug in Aptana Studio, not Tweepy (Aptana reports an error and highlights `get_user` in red, even though there is nothing actually wrong with the code).

Comment: @DSM...that's kind of what I think but being a newb wanted to check. Why doesn't Aptana do the same thing w/ other packages? btw, I am using tweepy version 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to not be warned about this you may exclude the warning:

goto Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Analysis

Click on the Undefined tab and add get_user to the textbox.  That will clear up your warning.

Andrew

Comment: Does your app throw an error when you try to run it?  I agree with Jason that with the information you've given us Aptana is incorrectly labeling get_user as undefined.  If that's not the case give us more info.

Comment: "The code actually runs fine with no errors and produces the expected results. "

Comment: Here's a link that may help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281955/pydev-say-unresolved-import-error

Answer (score 0):

I had a Problem similar to your case (also using PyDev with Aptana).

I upgraded Aptana and PyDev with the following instructions:

[Update PyDev on Aptana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25971061/4150548)

after the upgrade PyDev worked just fine for me :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.