# import pyodbc not working in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I am new to python..
I am not able to import pyodbc 
I am getting an error in eclipse (just for this import) 
i install pyodbc

```
C:\Users\app_rahavm>pip install pyodbc
Requirement already satisfied: pyodbc in c:\users\app_rahavm\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
```

python interpeter is also updated with the path:

[image: click here to see picture from eclipse]

and still i am getting

```
Unresolved import: pyodbc
```

when i write this:

```
import pyodbc
```

i also see this package under packages

[click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkpOj.png)

any ideas?

another thing i notice is that each install package has it's own .dist-info lib but i have only dist-info file which does not hav python files inside 
[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3eSG.png) [see content of lib here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIpEt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to update (if some else might need it... ) after spending alot of time on this ... the error is just a displayed error !! the code is running even with this error , this is very wierd but this is the case... also it is possible to press cntl + 1 and in the pop up screen choose "UnresolvedImport"

or just add at the end of the import - this will remove the red error and will do the import...

import pyodbc  # @UnresolvedImport

Answer (score 0):

Delete my old interpreter in `Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters`, and creating a new interpreter called "python" which had the correct paths. After quitting and reopening eclipse, pydev found all my modules.

See

[Pydev say, "Unresolved import" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281955/pydev-say-unresolved-import-error)

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip freeze` command to check whether the module is really present in the list of installed modules or not.