# import pyodbc not working in eclipse -python

Tags: python, eclipse

as a continue to this

[import pyodbc not working in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630440/import-pyodbc-not-working-in-eclipse)

can any one please explain to me how the pyodbc import should look like ? 
when i do

```
pip install pyodbc
```

or

```
 python -m pip install pyodbc-4.0.21-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

all i get is a folder

```
pyodbc-4.0.21.dist-info
```

which does not have any python files in it ...this is the content of the lib 
[lib content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjrDE.png)

is this is the right content? or there should be python files that need to be created some how

my problem is that eclipse does not recognize the import pyodbc

(getting `Unresolved import: pyodbc` )

**UPDATE**

when i open the consule from eclipse and writing

```
import pyodbc
```

i am not getting any errors 
just when doing import from the .py file (in the eclipse) i am getting the error
pleeeeeeeeese help

Comment: Are your path variables set correctly?

Comment: check with pip freeze

Comment: regarding path vars  - i thing i defined what i need , but maybe i am missing some thing...i defined PYTHON_HOME point to python.exe and added it to the PATH  - python --version is working . regaring pip freeze - i see the pyodbc when i run this command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to update (if some else might need it... ) after spending alot of time on this ... the error is just a displayed error !! the code is running even with this error , this is very wierd but this is the case...
also it is possible to press `cntl + 1`  and in the pop up screen choose "UnresolvedImport"

or just add at the end of the import - this will remove the red error and will do the import...

```
import pyodbc  # @UnresolvedImport
```