# Unresolved import: HTMLTestRunner

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, pydev

I'm getting **Unresolved import: HTMLTestRunner**

My code

```
import random
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner

class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.seq = range(10)

    def test_shuffle(self):
        # make sure the shuffled sequence does not lose any elements
        random.shuffle(self.seq)
        self.seq.sort()
        self.assertEqual(self.seq, range(10))

        # should raise an exception for an immutable sequence
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, random.shuffle, (1,2,3))
    @unittest.skip("Test Skipped1")
    def test_choicep(self):
        element = random.choice(self.seq)
        self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)
    @unittest.skip("Test Skipped2")
    def test_samplep(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            random.sample(self.seq, 20)
        for element in random.sample(self.seq, 5):
            self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestSequenceFunctions)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)

outfile = open("/Users/bhanusaa/Downloads/screenshots/", "w")
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
stream=outfile,title='Test Report',description='This demonstrates the report output by Prasanna.Yelsangikar.')

runner.run(suite)
```

i had downloaded **HTMLTestRunner** from http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html

and saved the **HTMLTestRunner.py** file in **/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages**

but still getting error

FYI i had configured all the required settings in **eclipse** and able to launch selenium   web driver script successfully, but when i'm trying to import HTMLTestRunner IM GETTING unresolved error

SYSTEM INFO.
**Python 2.7
pydev 2.2
OS MAC**

Comment: Please check the Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983088/unresolved-import-models

Answer (score 2):

**HTMLTestRunner** seems to have issue when installed using 'pip'. So as a workaround follow below steps:

1) Get the HTMLTestRunner  API from : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tungwaiyip/HTMLTestRunner/master/HTMLTestRunner.py

2) Save 'HTMLTestRunner.py' at 'C:\Python27\Lib'

3) Execute placed HTMLTestRunner from command prompt with below set of steps:

> > cd c:\Python27\Lib
> >
> > python HTMLTestRunner.py

[Check pyc created or not & Py file execution & navigation to .py file may vary depending on OS you are using needless to say]

4) Make sure environment variables set correctly

For confirming the installation successful:

> python
>
> import HTMLTestRunner
>
> return key