# Unresolved import models Django + Docker

Tags: python, django, docker

I have a few simple classes in my Django app that are not loading/importing properly. I know that the code works as I am Dockerizing over an existing app. I am fairly sure this is a similar issue to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983088/unresolved-import-models) but I do not know how to update this to use the Python inside my Docker container. I am following this guide (so all settings/configuration is the same).

I have 2 classes: a custom user class and a Company model, and I am trying to add a foreign key on the user that links it to a particular Company. On the other side, I will have a many to many relationships (a company can have multiple users).

`from core.models import Company`

VS Code says "unresolved import" when I hover on `core.models`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out (kind of) how to fix the problem. This [thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3840) was helpful, I added a setting to ignore unresolved imports, I also reordered my imports, also I was opening the folder that contained my app code (the root where the docker-compose.yml file lives) but I needed to open the actual code/source directory.

Setting:
`"python.analysis.disabled": [
        "unresolved-import"
    ]`