# Unresolved Import in PyDev (Eclipse) even if path is in global PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, pydev, pythonpath

I have the following code:

```
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')#@UndefinedVariable

import phantomjs


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ';'.join(sys.path)
```

I followed sth's answer in 
[Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)

and added the phantomjs.pth file to
~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
which is where

```
python -c 'import site; site._script()' --user-site
```

told me I needed to add the pth files. In the phantomjs.pth file, I put the path where the phantomjs.py file is:
/workspace/rankingmodel

It works for the python interpreter as

```
    print ';'.join(sys.path)
```

prints out (amongst others) /workspace/rankingmodel
but eclipse marks

```
import phantomjs
```

with the error

> Unresolved Import

How can I make that Eclispe and PyDev see the PYTHONPATH which I put in the .pth file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with *.pth files which are not automatically updated in Eclipse PyDev. So the solution is to remove and then re-add the python interpreter in Eclipse.

I found the answer which I was looking for in the answer by  Praveen Gollakota here:
[Importing using pydev and .pth files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196595/importing-using-pydev-and-pth-files)

For Linux, for Eclipse Kepler PyDev 3.9.1:

Drop down menu "Window", select "Preferences"
On the left-side menu: PyDev->Interpreters->Python Interpreter
Remove and re-add the python interpreter, and when you add it again make sure to click all the desired global python paths.

Answer (score 0):

One easy answer is to click on the Project menu, then Properties,
then under the PyDev - PYTHONPATH section click the External libraries tab 
and add again the required paths there.

This is the workaround I am currently using.

But I was wondering if there was a better solution where eclipse can see the global paths itself, without having to be told explicitely.