# Eclipse - Pydev, doesn't recognize not imported methods

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have Eclipse Version: 4.2.1 and PyDev version 2.7.1 installed on my 64-bit Ubuntu.
I am using Python 2.7 and I have this problem with Eclipse that it doesn't recognize my un-imported methods. For example if I write a code like this:

```
def main():
  myfiles = os.listdir('src')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
  print'done!'
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tset.py", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "tset.py", line 2, in main
    myfiles = os.listdir('src')
NameError: global name 'os' is not defined
```

which is a pretty obvious error because I didn't write "import os" at the beginning of my code. My problem is that Eclipse doesn't highlight these errors for me anymore. Either I have to find them by myself or I will find out about them when I run my code.
My Eclipse was working fine before but I don't know what did I change that this happened.

I should also mention that I have "lib" folder in my project and in that folder I have a few of my own modules and I have added the "lib" folder to PYTHONPATH of my project. And the code that I am running is in another folder named "test" and that's not in the PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I think same answer is here [Unresolved Import Issues with PyDev and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631377/unresolved-import-issues-with-pydev-and-eclipse)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unresolved Import Issues with PyDev and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631377/unresolved-import-issues-with-pydev-and-eclipse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that my code was in a folder like this:

> /MyProject/src/test/test.py

But the "src" folder was not in the PYTHONPATH. That is why Eclipse was not recognizing them as a source code and was not analyzing them.

To fix this go to:

> Eclipse -> Project -> Properties -> PyDev-PYTHONPATH -> Source Folders

and add "/MyProject/src" to source folders. (I only had "/MyProject/src/lib" in my source folders)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @183.amir, if one of your apps is symlinked (not an actual directory), you need to add it to PYTHONPATH separately (with the steps described above).