# unresolved import in eclipse pydev

Tags: eclipse, import

I just properly installed the google gdata library for python (the script actually runs fine). I'm working with pydev in eclipse. I imported a module but the import command remains curly red underlined as you can see on the screenshot.

[image]

I added the following und ProjectName->Properties, but it does not work (although the path is definitly correct):
[image]

What do I have to do such that the import is resovled correctly by eclipse?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have import statement like this: `import gdata.spreadsheet.service` then you need to make sure that on `PYTHONPATH` there is a directory that contains `gdata` subdirectory (and `gdata` should have `spreadsheet` subdirectory with `service.py` module file).

In your case: if your `gdata` directory is in `site-packages` directory on python distribution, then you need to make sure that `site-packages` is on PYTHONPATH (not `site-packages/gdata/spreadsheet` that you were trying to put there).

Look at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html in "6.4 Packages" section for example and reference.

In PyDev you can modify the contents of PYTHONPATH in two places:

- Window -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Python
- In the window you used

I would suggest you to first check that `site-packages` directory is in your `Window -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Python settings -> System PYTHONPATH`. It should be there by default, so if you didn't change it, it should be present there (and probably that's why your application works!).

Now, from some reasons, PyDev often has problems with "refreshing" info about available libraries after adding a new library to `site-packages` (and it uses that info for example to check if it should put error marker on import statement).

There are a few ways to force the refresh of this info. The most reliable for me is just removing python interpreter by means of: `Window -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Python -> Remove` and then adding it back in the same view. Then the `site-packages` directory is rescanned and PyDev sees the updated set of libraries, so the error markers should disappear.

Side note: To be honest, so far I haven't ever need to use this `External Libraries` view. Having site-packages in Interpreter settings is fine enought for 99% of cases because there is where Python external libraries should be put.

Comment: Great analysis and efficient solution.