# Unresolved import issue with Pydev

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pydev, xlrd

I'm trying to import the xlrd (Excel for python) library into Pydev.
I'm using python 3.3.2, eclipse 1.4, Pydev 0.4, xlrd 0.7.1.
my code is:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
    from xlrd import open_workbook
    File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1187
    print "EXTERNSHEET(b7-):"
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What I tried (according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631377/unresolved-import-issues-with-pydev-and-eclipse)):

- in the properties of the pydev project, add to "PyDev - PYTHONPATH" the xlrd folder, and site_packages folder as well
- change to `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages` instead of `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`
- remove the PyDev project config' by right clicking on the project. Then make it a PyDev project again
- delete the Python interpreter from "Python interpreters" and add it again
- add the xlrd folder in the interpreter
- File -> Restart" and not closing and reopening manually

Before I installed xlrd 0.7.1, I installed an advanced version (it didnt work also), but I deleted the library, before installing the 0.7.1 one.

Help :S

Comment: The best solution I found [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: were you able to figure this out?