# Python unresolved import

Tags: python, class, import

I am trying to import a class from a separate file into one of my modules. I have two files sampleModule and classB both in the same folder. Inside classB I have:

```
class CLASSB(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

Inside sampleModule, I have:

```
from classB import CLASSB
```

But in sampleModule I get this error:

```
Unresolved import: CLASSB
Unused import: CLASSB
```

I also have an **_*init*_**.py in the same folder

How do I fix this issue?

EDIT: Computer restart fixed issue.

Comment: Just to check, the file is called `classB.py` instead of `classB` right?

Comment: just curiosity: how many underscores You have in `_init_.py` file name ?

Comment: What version of python are you using? I've never seen this kind of error before

Comment: this looks like message of some code analysis tool

Comment: Probably relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631377/unresolved-import-issues-with-pydev-and-eclipse

Comment: class CLASSB ``def __init__`` is missing a colon.  When I add this and set up example structure as you describe, ``import sampleModule`` works fine.  No sign of the "unresolved import" problem

Comment: The colon's there, I just forgot to include it when typing the question. I am using python 2.7. I have two underscores for __init__.py. The file is called classB.py

Comment: "I just forgot to include it when typing the question" - you retyped your code into the question box? Don't do that. Copy and paste it from your actual source code, or we'll waste time trying to figure out what your code actually looks like and trying to guess at things you didn't realize were relevant.

Comment: The issue is fixed, the error went away when I restarted my computer.. weird.