# PyDev: Unresolved import: of .so file

Tags: python, pydev

I use PyDev for python, and I have 2 files - one obvious python script, second  - with extension .so. In my python script I want to use functions from .so file, so have line:

```
import test.so
```

But in PyDev editor this line is marked as error:

```
Unresolved import: test.so
Unresolved import: test
```

Could someone explain me why and how to fix this?

Comment: Why not simply `import test`?

Comment: I tried this, the result is the same

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631377/unresolved-import-issues-with-pydev-and-eclipse

Comment: I have this problem too! With an so file (cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so) that is not seen by eclipse or pydev using "import cv2" and listed as unresolved import. But python can find it, and all my scripts run fine.  Have you had any luck finding a solution?