# cython with python 3.5

Tags: python, cython

I am using python 3.53 cython 0.28.2 and Visual studio compiler 2017. 
The example was taken from:

http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html#cython-hello-world

I am trying to compile a simple helloworld.pyx

```
print ('hello world')
```

using visualstudio 2017. I tried two setup.py files

1st setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension("helloworld", ["helloworld.pyx"])]
)
```

2nd setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("helloworld.pyx")
)
```

both succeeded using

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace,
```

and generated the following dll:

```
helloworld.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
```

But when I import the generated pyd file using:

```
import helloworld.cp35-win_amd64
```

I get

import helloworld.cp35-win_amd64

```
                     ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Renaming the pyd file to shorter name without - or _ did not work.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What if `import helloworld`?

Comment: tried that.  No luck

Comment: That is the path you should take. What's the error? Probably the module isn't in *${PYTHONPATH}*.

Comment: I also renamed the pyd to helloworld.pyd and used import helloworld  No luck

Comment: The error is in the question starts after the line "I get" until end of line that starts with "SyntaxError"

Comment: The pyd file is in the same folder as the rest of the files.

Comment: What is the error if you use `import helloworld`?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/ Don't rename anything! The filename it generates is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple:

keep the generated pyd file name unchanged. Very important.

in the python script use import the pyd name until first dot.

in the above case

import helloworld

if you still get unresolved import error you can find a solution in this link:
[Unresolved Import Issues with PyDev and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631377/unresolved-import-issues-with-pydev-and-eclipse)