# Howto ignore specific undefined variables in Pydev Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, pydev

I'm writing a crossplatform python script on windows using Eclipse with the Pydev plugin. The script makes use of the `os.symlink()` and `os.readlink()` methods if the current platform isn't NT.

Since the `os.symlink()` and `os.readlink()` methods aren't available on the Windows platform Pydev flags them as undefined variables--like so:

[image: eclipse_undef_variable]

#### Question:

Is there a way to ignore specific undefined variable name errors *without* modifying my source file?

**edit**: I found a way to ignore undefined variable errors from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112715/how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors/2248987#2248987) on stackoverflow.
I'll leave the question open in case there is a way to solve this using project file or Pydev setting.

Comment: I know this isn't what you wanted to do, but for completeness:
You can get pydev to ignore these things by adding the comment #@UndefinedVariable after the line where os.symlink/os.readlink is.

You probably already tried the Ctrl-1 solution, but I just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: That's the solution I'm currently using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect pydev may have better, specific solutions, but what about just putting some code at the start of your program, such as:

```
if not hasattr(os, 'symlink'): os.symlink = None
```

Yeah, it's a hack, but, unless pydev *does* have specialized solutions (unfortunately I don't know of any, but then I'm no pydev expert;-), may be better than nothing...

Comment: I would rather not change my source code to deal with Pydev if at all possible. Also it appears that you have to do this at the method/function level for each undefined variable (doing this globally didn't work for me).


Hopefully there are settings that I can add to my Pydev project file.

Answer (score 3):

I use pydev + pylint.

With pylint you can add which messages to ignore in the Preferences>Pydev>Pylint>"Aggruments to pass to pylint" section.

```
--disable-msg=W0232,F0401
```

You can ignore messages in-line as well with comments:

```
os.symlink(target, symlink) # IGNORE:<MessageID>
```

Mouse-over the "x" where the line numbers are to see the message id.

Comment: Does pylint disable the normal pydev messages or is that just to ignore them in pylint?   Also, I don't get a message id when mousing-over the "x" -- just 'undefined error from import: symlink'.

Comment: pylint is somewhat of an add-on.  You may be using the Pydev>Editor>Code Analysis feature.  (Check if "Do code analysis?" is checked) I'm not familiar with how this feature works.

Comment: This is another sytnax: os.symlink(target, symlink) #@UndefinedVariable

Comment: Meanwhile [pylint can use human readable message ids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955361/list-of-pylint-human-readable-message-ids): `# pylint disable=undefined-variable`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed PyDev doesn't recognize ZeroMQ constants so I struggled with the same problem.

I found PyDev has a settings option in `Preferences >  PyDev > Code Editor > Code Analysis` : `Undefined`-tab. Just write `symlink` and `readlink` there (comma separated) to remove the errors.

Still not optimal, but good enough for now.