# List of pylint human readable message ids?

Tags: python, pylint

Recent versions of pylint allow for suppressing messages with human readable message ids. For example, instead of

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):  # pylint: disable=R0904
    ...
```

you can specify:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):  # pylint: disable=too-many-public-methods
    ...
```

This [page](http://www.logilab.org/card/pylintfeatures) lists the numeric message ids. However, I'm looking for a complete list of the human readable versions of the message ids. Where can I find that list?

Comment: Why this question was marked as off topic seems to be beyond human comprehension. The author asked for a place that lists all human readable messages not about opinion about them.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I don't think there exists (yet) such list on the web, though `pylint --list-msgs` automatically produces one.

Comment: No longer true, see my answer below for the link to the pylint docs online: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70829006/733309

Answer (score 31):

I've stumbled upon your question, searching for such a list myself. So I decided to process `pylint --list-msgs` through regex. Then I created such a list. You can access it [here](https://github.com/b0wl/readable-pylint-messages/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Nice, but it seems quite a few of the descriptions are incomplete. For example: "empty-docstring

C0112 - Empty %s docstring

Used when a module, function, class or method has an empty docstring (it would be too easy" <- incomplete description

Comment: @FrankNiessink, thanks for pointing this out. My regex was off. Could not handle it, so changed way i split output.

Answer (score 3):

You can find it buried in the pylint documentation here: https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html#pylint-checkers-options-and-switches

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/ethanchewy/PythonBuddy/blob/master/PythonBuddy/pylint_errors/pylint_errors.py) is a dictionary of pylint errors to message for the most the most updated version of the `pylint --list-msgs`.

The format is PYLINT_ERROR_ID: ERROR_MESSAGE.

Comment: +1 for the info, however it doesn't include the abbreviations OP wanted, just the codes and full messages.