# Module 'pygame' has no 'QUIT' memberPylint(E1101:no-member)

Tags: python, pygame

I'm following along with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jO6qQDNa2UY&t=1444s&ab_channel=TechWithTim

My code is the same from the video but the pygame.QUIT isn't working. It was before but not sure what happened.

Here's my code

```
import pygame
import os

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500   #Y, X
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

pygame.display.set_caption("First Game!")

#definding varibles#
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
FPS = 60
SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT = 55, 40

#inporting images    these images in pygame are know as surfaces
YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_yellow.png'))
YELLOW_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.scale(YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT))

RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_red.png'))
RED_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.scale(RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT))

def draw_window(): 
    WIN.fill(WHITE)
    WIN.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP, (300,100))
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)    #ensurces that we will not go over our FPS, makes the game consistent on diff computers
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        draw_window()


    pygame.quit() 
   
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your code is working fine here. Please add the error you're seeing.

Comment: Does this help? [Module 'pygame' has no 'QUIT' member](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53030345/13552470)

Comment: The error is E1101: no member

Comment: Does pygame.locals.QUIT work?