# Why is there an error when i use pygame in vscode but not in pycharm?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame

so this is exactly what I wrote in vs code

```
import pygame


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 600, 500

WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

running = True

while running:
 for event in pygame.event.get():
  if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
   running = False
```

I get the error Module 'pygame' has no 'QUIT' member
there is an error in if statement

```
   if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

its pygame.QUIT

Comment: There is no error in this code. The issue is related to your system. Do you get a runtime error when you run the code or is it just a lint error?

Comment: post the full, unaltered traceback that you get.

Comment: should I copy-paste the error in the vs code terminal

Comment: Are you using `pylint`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012461/imports-failing-in-vscode-for-pylint-when-importing-pygame

Comment: it says pylint(no-member)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: do you get this error when you run code or when you only write code? Maybe it is only warning and you shouldn't bother this. All tools may have mistakes.

Comment: I get this when I write my code

Answer (score 0):

Reason: For security reasons, Pylint only trusts C extensions from the standard library stdlib by default, but the module "pygame" does not come from it.

Please add the following settings in `settings.json` to add it to the whitelist:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--extension-pkg-whitelist=pygame"],
```

[image]

Or use the following settings:

```
 "python.linting.pylintArgs": [ "--errors-only", "--generated-members=pygame.* " ]
```

[image]