# Python: How can I use variable from main file in module?

Tags: python, global-variables

I have 2 files main.py and irc.py.
main.py

```
import irc
var = 1
func()
```

irc.py

```
def func():
    print var
```

When I try to run main.py I'm getting this error

> NameError: global name 'var' is not defined

How to make it work?

@Edit
I thought there is a better solution but unfortunately the only one i found is to make another file and import it to both files
main.py

```
import irc
import another
another.var = 1
irc.func()
```

irc.py

```
import another
def func():
    print another.var
```

another.py

```
var = 0
```

Answer (score 11):

Don't. Pass it in. Try and keep your code as decoupled as possible: one module should not rely on the inner workings of the other. Instead, try and expose as little as possible. In this way, you'll protect yourself from having to change the world every time you want to make things behave a little different.

**main.py**

```
import irc
var = 1
func(var)
```

**irc.py**

```
def func(var):
    print var
```

Comment: It would be easier for me to move this function to main file instead of adding this argument

Comment: @gr56: Then it sounds like refactoring is in order. If that's not possible either, I'd go with your solution of a third module which contains just the `var` object and is imported by both. If that works for you, please post it as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: @SamirTalwar You can do this for functions, what about for instantiation of classes? For example, you want to define instances of a class in another module which you can import. The arguments can't be placeholders in this case.

Comment: It works for me only when I execute `irc.py` earlier (run script). I use Python 3 and Spyder. If not I get name `func` is not defined.

Answer (score 9):

Well, that's my code which works fine:

func.py:

```
import __main__
def func():
    print(__main__.var)
```

main.py:

```
from func import func

var="It works!"
func()
var="Now it changes!"
func()
```

Comment: I like this solution and it works ... but eclipse gives me an 'Undefined variable from import: var' error on any imported variable or function from main.  Any way of getting around this?

Comment: see [how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112715/how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors)

Answer (score 4):

Two options.

```
from main import var

def func():
    print var
```

This will copy a reference to the original name to the importing module.

```
import main

def func():
    print main.var
```

This will let you use the variable from the other module, and allow you to change it if desired.

Comment: Oh, this is just wrong. Mutual imports give me the heebie jeebies.

Comment: Then you just don't know what you're doing. Mutual imports are perfectly safe, and work fine given certain very clear restrictions.

Comment: @Ignacio: And they'll work fine in this toy code designed to highlight the problem. I have doubts they'll work as expected in the real thing. Even if they do, they will encourage fuzzy lines between modules which serve only to make adding new features and maintaining the old ones so much more difficult than it has to be. I can't imagine a situation where mutual imports work better than a third module that serves the original two.

Comment: This would be the best option for me but it gives me an error:  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'func'

Comment: Then you've violated one of those restrictions.

Comment: @gr56: It should be `__main__` instead of `main`

Comment: @Kable: I don't think so: ImportError: cannot import name var

Answer (score 0):

Well, var in the function isn't declared.  You could pass it as an argument.
main.py

```
import irc
var = 1
func(var)
```

irc.py

```
def func(str):
    print str
```

Answer (score 0):

What Samir said works for Python 2

For python 3 you need to do it this way.

main.py

```
import irc
from irc import func

var = 1
func(var)
irc.py
```

irc.py

```
def func(var):
    print(var)
```