# How should I share a variable across different classes?

Tags: python, global-variables

I have a test suite function in `runTests.py` and I run the tests from this file:

```
def suite():
    suite.addTest(makeSuite(Class1))
    suite.addTest(makeSuite(Class2))
    ...
    suite.addTest(makeSuite(ClassN))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # grab argument from the command line and
    # initiate myVar1 and myVar2 here before running the suite
    # run the suite here
```

What I want is to read in arguments from the command line and initiate them inside `runTests.py`, right before I run the suite in the `if` statement. These variables would also be used inside of `Class1`, `Class2`, etc.

Would it be correct if inside `runTests.py` I have the following before the suite definition

```
myVar1 = 'defaultValue'
myVar2 = 'defaultValue'
```

Then in the `if` statement grab the arguments from the command line and initialize `myVar1` and `myVar2`. So in the other classes, eg `Class1`, I would import it like:

```
from runTests import myVar1
from runTests import myVar2
```

Basically, what I want is to read in a few parameters from the command line and be able to use those values in the other classes. Thanks!

Comment: "Pass them in" -- or this this *specifically* about a unit-testing scenario? (Also, don't confuse a class with a package.)

Comment: this is the scenario I have, I assume it wouldn't be any different even if it was unit-testing, I'm not sure. My tests are actually Selenium Tests. My Class1, Class2 are each a file with one class in it that holds test functions.

Comment: Because one can often turn a blind eye in the case of unit-testing :) e.g. is the intent a "super global" variable or a "configuration" or ...? The cleanest, IMOHO, is often to pass data *in* to objects (e.g. by the constructor or method call), instead of requiring objects to go out and find data. At the very moment a dependency on `runTests` is added then the classes are no longer valid outside of the testing framework. Also, note that if the `from` occurs outside of something that is delay-executed (e.g. a constructor or method) then it will lead to "cyclic import issue".

Comment: However, your conclusion is correct -- that global variables from `runTests` can be accessed after it is `import`ed (using the `from...import` does *not* create aliases, but rather creates a new local binding which will initially name the same object). Do pay attention to the "cyclic import issue" and *order* of operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [this from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011371/python-how-can-i-use-variable-from-main-file-in-module?rq=1) which works.
Basically, putting my shared variables `myVar1` and `myVar2` into a new file `myfile.py` then `import myfile` in `runTests.py` and assign a value to the variables like this:

```
myfile.myVar1 = sys.argv[1]
```

In the other files that need to use `myVar1`, `import myfile` and use the variable like this:

```
myfile.myVar1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
params = sys.argv
```

sys.argv will give you a list

```
$ python myproram.py var1 var2 var3
```

sys.argv[0] => myprogram.py

sys.argv[1] => var1

sys.argv[2] => var2

etc

You can access this in any classes

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import sys


class addc:
    def __init__(self , no1 , no2):
        self.no1 = no1
        self.no2 = no2
    def addition(self):
        total = self.no1 + self.no2
        return total



if len (sys.argv) !=3:
    print "no u cant go forwrd"
    print "agument is less"
    sys.exit()

obj_initial = addc(2 , 3 ) 
ans1 = obj_initial.addition() 
print " the total of internla argumnet is %i"%ans1

cmnd_argu1 = int(sys.argv[1]) 
cmnd_argv2 = int (sys.argv[2])

obj_cmnd_argu = addc(cmnd_argu1 , cmnd_argv2)
ans2_cmnd_argu = obj_cmnd_argu.addition()
print " the total of internla argumnet is %i" % int(ans2_cmnd_argu)
```