# How to use global functions in function from separate module?

Tags: python, tkinter, namespaces

I have a program that writes a separate in order to make a series of similar functions. These functions are to call another function, checkbuy, from the main source code. Whenever I try this, it says it's not defined. Globalizing the main function in the module functions fails.

Module function:

```
def buyMagikarp():
     global pokenums
     if checkbuy(10,1): #calling the function from main file
          pokenums['Magikarp']+=1
          Magikarp.config(text='Magikarp: '+str(pokenums['Magikarp']))
```

This function is used inside of a Tkinter Button object, and is successfully called when the button is clicked.

Function in main:

```
def checkbuy(price,amount):
    global coin, coingainnum
    if coin >= price:
        coin-=price
        updatecoin()
        coingainnum+=amount
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Module function works in works when in main.

How to call function from function in local namespace?

Comment: You would need to import it. I'm guessing that `main` already imports the module, so you can't also import `main` from the module because that would be circular. I would move `checkbuy` to another module (`lib` or something more descriptive), which you can then import in both `main` and the other modules

Comment: Did you import the module? Why do you *expect* `checkbuy` to be in scope in the other module?

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011371/python-how-can-i-use-variable-from-main-file-in-module). Although it's about a variable not a function; so the solution of passing the variable as a parameter doesn't really apply here (you could do it but **don't**).

Comment: I am trying to write a series of similar functions based off a list. The module function was an example of one of these. That's why I need the separate module.

Comment: I moves the required functions and variables to the module and that fixed it. I was just hoping there was another way.