# Django incorrect import

Tags: django, aptana, django-sites

I am developing a web app with django 1.2.4, but I am having a problem with the Site model. I try:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
...
if Site._meta.installed:
    ...
```

I am getting the error `undefined variable from import: _meta` in the if statement,
any help?

Comment: Where are you running that? Devserver?

Comment: Works in 1.3.0.  I know that doesn't answer your question, but maybe take a look at the change logs.  Or, just look in the Site class.

Comment: @Lycha I am running in localhost for now

Comment: Can you post the full Traceback?

Comment: I get the error in the IDE (apatana Studio 3)

Comment: Aptana uses pydev. see updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you've fiddled with the django source, there really should be any problems with the `Sites._meta.installed` variable. `_meta.installed` is assigned from [within the metaclass of all models](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.4/django/db/models/base.py#L53) (using [`contribute_to_class()`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.4/django/db/models/options.py#L58)) so it would affect ALL models if the code were broken.

A quick [search](https://code.djangoproject.com/search) for relevant tickets does not reveal such a problem for that version (or any other version) of django.

Are you by any chances running [django via pydev](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html)? If so, perhaps this post is relevant: [How do I fix PyDev "Undefined variable from import" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112715/how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors)

That's of course a wild speculation on my part. If you can post a Trackback of your error, we might be able to get a better insight into your problem.

---

#### Response to comments:

> "I get the error in the IDE (apatana Studio 3)"

[Aptana uses PyDev](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html#note-for-users-with-aptana-studio-3-beta) and so will exhibit the same problem. Here's a possible fix taken from [this blog post](http://mitchfournier.com/2010/06/18/aptana-studio-and-undefined-variable-from-import-doesnotexist/):

1. Open up Aptana Studio
2. Open Window > Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Code Analysis
3. Select the “Undefined” tab
4. Add DoesNotExist at the end of the “Consider the following names as globals” list
5. Apply and restart

Comment: Tried this solution with LiClipse and still get the undefined variable from import: _meta error... at least now I know the issue is with the IDE!