# Vscode can't use the function "go to definition" and can not open file in PROBLEMS

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm using VScode for my python project on macOS, but I cannot use the function of go to definition and can not open file in PROBLEMS.

For example:
when I control-click (macOS) and select go to definition, it raise a warning like this:

Unable to open 'spider.py': A system error occurred (ENOTDIR: not a directory, stat '/Users/gassy/Documents/python_spider/toutiao/spider.py/Users/gassy/Documents/python_spider/toutiao/spider.py').

Also, when I click an entry listed in PROBLEMS, it also give the same error:
[image: screenshot of the error]

It seems like a problem creating the path to the file as the path is repeated in the error message like `path/to/file.py/path/to/file.py`

Go to Definition works for global variables.

**System**: macOS Mojave

**Version**: VScode 1.30.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939751/pylint-unresolved-import-error-in-visual-studio-code explains how to modify .vscode/settings.json by adding "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./path-to-your-code"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ,I find the reason!
I thought this bug may be produced by an extension, so I reinstalled VScode for many times followed the method of this website 
[uninstall-remove-vscode-mac](https://medium.com/@jimkang/complete-uninstall-remove-vscode-mac-5e48bef3bdec)
and tried to find the reason.

When I install Visual Studio IntelliCode, it ask me to install Microsoft Python Language Server. After that, this bug happened.

Hope this solution will help you.

Comment: What was your solution regarding `Microsoft Python Language Server`? Did you just ignored the VS Code prompt and did not install it?

Answer (score 2):

You can install the extension **pydev** in vscode.
The extension website is https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabioz.vscode-pydev

If you using Python3, Please visit the official website 
http://www.pydev.org/vscode/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answers that are just a little more than a link may be deleted. Please ensure your answer is useful by adding some more information.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me.

And it turn out to be the Chinese path that caused this problem.

Copy the folder to a path that contains no Chinese character, and things work well for me

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall/Reinstall or Disable/Enable all extensions did not work for me.

Clearing all cache of VScode however helped me to solve this problem.
For this, delete all files from the cache folder: `C:\Users\\{Your Username}\AppData\Roaming\Code`

Comment: The cache folder is at the `/home/user/.config/Code` under Linux. The cache folder is `/Users/<userid>/Library/Application Support/Code/Local Storage` on macOS.