# PYTHONPATH naming restrictions for vscode python linting

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using vscode with python and other languages in a single project.  The directory structure is like this:

```
- base
 - python
  - foo
    foo.py
  - bar
    bar.py
 - bin
 - etc
```

I am getting 'python(unresolved import)' warnings in vscode when importing modules such as 'foo'.

I used a solution provided by Tomasz C. here:
[Pylint "unresolved import" error in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939751/pylint-unresolved-import-error-in-visual-studio-code)

In my case I have a .env file with

```
PYTHONPATH=python/
```

This does not work!

I have renamed this portion of my directory structure to anything else (like PYTHONPATH=python2/) and it does work.

I have also tried multiple linters with no change.

I am not in control of the naming of these directories.  Is there some way I can get linting with vscode to work with existing directory structure?

Answer (score 1):

`PYTHONPATH` should point to a valid `python` executable instance, it should be the one being used by your environment, so you have to give it the full absolute path, not a relative one. example: `/home/user/environment/bin/python`, change it according to your setup.

Comment: You are referring to a different python path.  There is python.pythonPath in the settings.json, which refers to the executable.  I am referring to the environment variable PYTHONPATH: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Comment: OH, ok, then use just `python` **without** the trailing slash you put `/` or try: `environment/bin/python` (change according your environment setup)

Comment: Thanks, but still no go.  I should reiterate that it works with any text other than 'python'.  Example: 'pythona' works.