# Unresolved import selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have just downloaded Visual Studio Code and tried to run some Python code.
However, when I try to import Seleinum I receive the following error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Erros:
module selenium
unresolved import 'selenium'Python(unresolved-import)
unresolved import 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys' Python(unresolved-import)
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: You can refer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939751/pylint-unresolved-import-error-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0):

The links below address the issue you are having. Your workspace settings are improperly configured. By adding the PATH of the virtual environment library/packages to the workspace settings, settings.json, file will correct the issue.

An example of my configuration in Windows 10:

```
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\python-virtual-environments\\env\\lib",
```

[Pylint "unresolved import" error in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939751/pylint-unresolved-import-error-in-visual-studio-code)

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations

Comment: Where must i paste this Code?

Comment: Under workspace settings in the settings.json file.  I included links as to where I obtained the information. I tested it to make sure it works.