# Unresolved import error - Python virtual-environment

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, visual-studio-code, macos-mojave

I have created a virtual environment in VSCode on mac os.

I have pip installed 'requests' module in the virtual environment. The environment is activated.
When I import the requests module in my program, it gives the required output but it shows a problem that - "Unresolved import error".

I have attached a screenshot that shows the exact problem. You can also see that output is generated and the module is installed in the virtual environment folder.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pylint "unresolved import" error in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939751/pylint-unresolved-import-error-in-visual-studio-code) (more specifically the 2nd answer)

Comment: @KaranShishoo - Thank you, I appreciate your help. I had changed the 'pythonPath' to path/python3.
I changed it back to path/python and it worked. Any clue why ?