# Unresolved import in my django project : VSCode

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I have a Django project called `ubm-app` with two apps, `main` and `ubm-app`. I've created a couple of classes, `URLAdder` and `URLModifier` in the `views.py` file in the `main` app. Im trying to import these views into my `urls.py` file by using the line `from . import views` but VS Code shows me the error `unresolved import 'c:\Users\Hari\Desktop\django\UBM-App\main.'`.

This is my `urls.py` file.

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('api/add/', views.URLAdder.as_view()),
    path('api/modify/',views.URLModifier.as_view()),
]
```

This is the `settings.json` file found when I use the `Configure Language Specific Settings...` option.

```
{
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "[python]": {



    }
}
```

This is the `settings.json` file in the `.vscode` folder in my Django project.

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "env\\Scripts\\python.exe"
}
```

Can anyone please suggest a fix to this with an explanation? I seem to be having these unresolved import errors time and again. Forgive me if the error is a basic one.

Comment: Did you install pylint? That is often the issue when it comes to false import error messages in VSCode

Comment: @Hybrid yes, I have installed pylint-django. The version is 2.0.15 and the pylint version is 2.4.4, but I dont quite understand its necessity here because importing has worked without pylint before and I dont see the people around me doing this to be able to import peacefully.

Comment: Can you provide the entire traceback?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with wrong unresolved import errors in vscode. I suggest that you see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939751/pylint-unresolved-import-error-in-visual-studio-code) as one of the answers might solve your problem as well.

Comment: The right answer seems to be to use following setting in the workspace settings `.vscode/settings.json` :

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./path-to-your-code"],
```

Though, is it necessary to do this everytime I initialize a project in Django? Because importing has worked in the past a time or two without this. Thanks so far.

Comment: Well, it seems that this approach solves the problem for this specific project, not the others. Though in my case, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56464813/6287044) solved the problem. So, check this one too.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Solution:
On your Vscode/setting.json simply place the "Python.autoComplete.extraPaths" to correspond to your Project File so that when you import a Module on your script, Your pyDev server can detect it and show no error to your Code.
e.g
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./path-to-your-script-code"],

Remember to inlude your Project folder along the path to your actual code file

[image]