# Visual Studio Code "Go To Definition" only works within the same file Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm having some issues with the "Go To Definition" feature in Visual Studio Code and Python code. To note, I haven't tested with other coding languages. The feature works well for functions and variables within the same open file but it does not work for files being imported such as custom classes or custom .py files that I import. This is true even if the file/class in question is open in another tab.

[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWLJk.png)

Is there a reason for this? If so, can it be fixed?

Comment: Which language server are you using? I.e. what is `"python.jediEnabled"` set to? Have you tried the opposite value to see what that results in?

Comment: @BrettCannon I have "python.jediEnabled": false since I am using Visual Studio IntelliCode

Comment: @BrettCannon I have. Then VSCode throws an error stating that the IntelliCode requires other engines to be disabled and then the jediEnabled setting gets set to false automatically.

Comment: Correct, IntelliCode does not work with Jedi.

Comment: Thanks @BrettCannon. it seems that even with IntelliCode "off" and Jedi "on" the "Go To Definition" does not work.

Comment: If you can come up with a small, reproducible example then please open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python

Answer (score 0):

see [Pylint "unresolved import" error in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939751/pylint-unresolved-import-error-in-visual-studio-code) explains how to modify .vscode/settings.json by adding "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./path-to-your-code"]

Comment: Thanks @JasonHarrison. I tried adding the extraPaths as suggested but it still did not work. Maybe I'm missing something? I added the path as follows: "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["C:/Repositories"] and "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["C:/Repositories/"], none of which worked.

Comment: Please try paths that result in directories where your py files are. I had to add my subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks @JasonHarrison. I tried adding the path(s) as you suggested, but it still doesn't work. I'm using PyLance, so, the python.autoComplete.extraPaths has be replaced by python.analysis.extraPaths.