# How to solve 'unresolved import discord.ext.tasks'?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to create a Discord bot using Python for my server. I read the documentation of discord.py and tried to run the sample posted there. The code is running, but don't know why I have this warning "unresolved import discord.ext.tasks". Tried with Python 3.7 and got none of the packages imported. Anyone can help me solving that?

[the error + code (photo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kxvb.png)

Comment: The answer to this question already exists. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939751/pylint-unresolved-import-error-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: One more thing, always include the code here and try to not attach screenshots of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use visual studio 2019 it cant import discord.ext correctly, I had the same issue use Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
from discord.ext import commands
```

Instead use

```
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
```