# unresolved import 'youtube_search' discord.py visual studios

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.8

I've tried so many things to resolve my import such as pip installing it, uninstalling it and reinstalling, upgrading it, and force installing but I still get the same error. I've also tried putting this in my settings.json:
 `"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./Users/Pc/Downloads/ingcog.py/cogs/music.py"],` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939751/pylint-unresolved-import-error-in-visual-studio-code)

Full settings.json:

```
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Toph1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe",
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./Users/Pc/Downloads/ingcog.py/cogs/music.py"],
}
```

Comment: Have you tired setting `python.pythonPath` to the directory and not the exe as was done in the linked answer? In your case this would be `"C:\\Users\\Toph1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38"`

Comment: @Benjin I just did and It still doesn't work.