# I can't import openpyxl in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I used the command `pip3 install openpyxl`, but I'm still getting the error, *unresolved import 'openpyxl'*.

How I can import the library or fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pylint "unresolved import" error in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939751/pylint-unresolved-import-error-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Enter the currently selected [environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) in the terminal: （ shortcut keys: Ctrl+Shift+` ）I use a virtual environment.

   [image]
2. Install the module "`openpyxl`" in your currently selected VScode environment:

   [image]
3. Reopen this file or reload VSCode after installation:

   [image]

Check the installation:

We can see the installation package of the module "`openpyxl`" under "`.venv`" of the virtual environment used.

[image]