# No definition found for function - VSCode Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode for Python along with the Microsoft for Python extension enabled in VSCode.

For **Python v3.9.0** I am getting **No definition found** if I try to seek a function definition.

[image]

However, I do not get the error if I use my Conda Virtual environment for Python 3.7.0

What might be the problem?

Comment: Are you using the last version of Python VScode Extension?

Comment: I am using `v2020.9.114305` and I think that's the latest one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939751/pylint-unresolved-import-error-in-visual-studio-code explains how to modify .vscode/settings.json by adding "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./path-to-your-code"]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When I used the code you provided and disabled the `Python` extension, I encountered the same problem as you.

Since "`Go to Definition`" is supported by the corresponding language service extension, it is recommended that you check that the current `Python` extension is available and confirm that the selected [python interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) is also available. In addition, please try to reload VSCode.

Comment: Thank you.  My VsCode Python interpreter was changed and that fixed mine.

Answer (score 41):

I had the same problem and changing the python language server from Jedi to Microsoft or Pylance did fix the problem. To do this go to the settings with `Cntrl + ,` and search for `python.languageserver`

Comment: setting it to "Microsoft" fixed the issue for me

Comment: After literal months of troubleshooting this problem your answer FINALLY solved it for me. I can go to definition, and intellisense is working properly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Interestingly, in my case switching from Pylance to Jedi fixed it

Comment: This concept worked for me and switching from default to Pylance worked. (Microsoft wasn't an available option for me)

Comment: Microsoft was not present for me also, Pylance did not work, but Jedi does fix the problem for me. So weird.

Comment: Microsoft was not present for me as well. Using Jedi fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem after installing some conda packages that may have interfered with the already present pip packages.

**My solution was the following:**

- set your Python Interpreter (you find it by typing "interpreter" in Command Palette) to the correct version of Python.
- add within your `settings.json` file the option: `"python.languageServer" : "Microsoft"`. Save file.
- restart VS Code.

*Note* on how to open Command Palette: simply type `ctrl-P` (on Windows).

*Note* on how to open `settings.json` file (if you are a noob like me): open the command palette and search for "settings", then "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)".

Comment: Error editing settings.json:
Value is not accepted. Valid values: "Default", "Jedi", "Pylance", "None".

Answer (score 2):

- install `pylance` extension
- `preferences -> settings`, serach "languageserver", select `Pylance`

Answer (score 1):

Making sure you're using a correct interpreter will allow you to import third-party packages installed for that interpreter.

However, if you're trying to lookup a definition for your own module, make sure your `PYTHONPATH` is set correctly and that you have an empty `__init__.py` inside your module.

Let's say your module is defined inside

```
[project_root]/src/my_library
```

Your `PYTHONPATH` defined in `.env` file (located in the project root) should contain:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:./src
```

(note that, in Windows, the separator is `;` and not `:`). Also, make sure you have created the file `[project_root]/src/my_library/__init__.py`

Answer (score 1):

after upgrading python to 3.9 I had this issue.  I found that **Python: Default Interpreter Path** was still pointing at 2.7.

I also switched the **Python: Language Server** to Pylance.  I'll experiment with Language server to see if that has an effect.  before this I was getting Language server has crashed 3x not restarting it.  After reinstalling that, I don't get that error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pylint`, which worked for me.

Install pylint by running:

```
pip install -U pylint --user
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers regarding python interpreter are out of date on version 1.68 as interpreter selection is explicitly done on start of jupyter notebook files. But I had the same problem , what worked for me was one or more of the following steps - not sure exactly what fixed it.

1. uninstalled kite (saw a post somewhere saying it interferes with go to defintion functionality)
2. CTRL SHIFT P - Reload with all extensions disabled
3. CTRL SHIF P - Reload Window
   on this last reload an option at the right bottom allowed reload with all extension enabled
   after this, the go to definition started working for functions I had defined in other .py files

Answer (score -1):

Recently, I faced a similar issue. In my case, it was an issue of go modules.

Just running `go mod verify` worked like a charm.