# python "unresolved import" in visual studio code

Tags: python

I use visual studio code for python, and recently installed the Python extension by microsoft because of its many features. But whenever I import something, (i.e "import numpy", "from flask import Flask",etc), I see a warning that says "unresolved import". This happens even in the django imports, which are imported by default(like "from django.shortcuts import render").
At first, I thought about ignoring these warnings, but they are getting annoying now. And I am pretty sure I have installed those modules.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you check this before? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939751/pylint-unresolved-import-error-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Yeah. I had searched for this on google and found this. But the solution works only on some imports. Today, I imported 'feedparser' with "import feedparser", and still the warning was coming

Comment: are you using venv?