# Unable to import 'pygame' in Visual Studio Code on MacOS

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to import pygame in V.S. Code on MacOS, but, it throws me an error:-

```
Unable to import 'pygame' pylint(import-error)[1,1]
```

I have already installed pygame using:-

```
pip install pygame
```

But, when I run the code, the output shows:-

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

Would appreciate it if anyone could please let me know how could I resolve this issue and import pygame successfully on V.S. Code on MacOS! Thanks for the help:)

Comment: Why are you installing Pygame version 1.9.6? The latest version is 2.0.1

Comment: @Rabbid76 I just typed the command pip install pygame in terminal! And, didn't mentioned any specific version go Pygame!

Comment: I've also run this command by the past and I needed to type manually `pip install --upgrade pygame` to get the newer version. Now there is no problem after reinstalling python, maybe it is because the `pip` version was too old.

Comment: I think the duplicate closure is wrong. It is not about installing pygame, but rather pylint on VS Code not finding the path to the site-packages where pygame is *already* installed Running the code works as OP mentioned, so it is *already* installed. Just need to configure pylint.

Comment: @GinoMempin Thanks for your help! Highly Appreciate it:)

Comment: Possibly better duplicate: [Pylint “unresolved import” error in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53939751/2745495)