# PySimpleGUI is only showing black screen (python)

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

When i start this python script:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text("Hello from PySimpleGUI")], [sg.Button("OK")]]

# Create the window
window = sg.Window("Demo", layout)

# Create an event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    # End program if user closes window or
    # presses the OK button
    if event == "OK" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

I get this GUI instead of a text with button: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode I had to update the settings.json of python

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/your/venv/bin/python",
```

Reference: [Pylint "unresolved import" error in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939751/pylint-unresolved-import-error-in-visual-studio-code)