# about python pyramid view

Tags: python, pyramid

My project is based on Pyramid.

Pyramid's default scaffold is very simple: `view.py`, `models.py`, and so on.

I created some directories to replace them. For example:

`view.py` -->  view directory

`models.py` --> model directory

Then I create a file named `login.py`:

```
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPForbidden
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.view import view_config
import logging

from ..model import (
    DBSession,
    DynUser,
    )

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def find_user(account):
    #user = None
    try:
        user = DBSession.query(DynUser).filter(DynUser.username==account).first()
        #one = DBSession.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.name=='one').first()
    except ValueError:
        #log.warning("invalidate id %s input." % request.matchdict['id'])
        log.warning("invalidate id %s input.")
    except Exception:
        log.error("database error!")

    if not user:
        return HTTPForbidden()

    return dict(user=user)
```

I have imported DBSession. Why do I still get this error?

```
tip
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Undefined variable from import: DBSession

Undefined variable from import: DBSession

DBSession Found at: dyncms.model.meta


DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention it, but I'll assume you moved `models.py` to `model/__init__.py`.

`from ..models` only works if `login.py` is in a subdir (like `login/login.py`). If it's not the case, you should use `from .models import`.

Comment: In model directory __init__.py # package from .meta import DBSession from .meta import Base meta.py from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base from sqlalchemy.orm import ( scoped_session, sessionmaker, ) from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension())) Base = declarative_base()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112715/how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors

Comment: Try running the code directly on the command line to make sure. If the problem is due to pydev, you should close this question.

Answer (score 0):

In model directory

```
__init__.py 
# package
from .meta import DBSession
from .meta import Base
from .book import Book

meta.py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    scoped_session,
    sessionmaker,
    )

from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
Base = declarative_base()
```