# Undefined variables from input in PyDev project

Tags: python

I use `LiClipse` as my Python IDE. I imported two given skeletons in order to extend them (my first Python project). I created a PyDev project and dragged and dropped the files beneath the root of the project. The `.py` file declares the following import statements:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
```

Every use of `cv2` or `np` results in an `Undefined variable from input`. Is this question identical to [How do I fix PyDev "Undefined variable from import" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112715/how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors) (with a proposed solution of just ignoring the error in the IDE) or did I forget some settings?

[image]
[image]

Comment: what error you got, give traceback

Comment: I already see the error symbols when just opening the file in the IDE.

Comment: Have you define `PYTHONPATH` in IDE ?

Comment: I selected the (default) radio button 'Add project directory to the PYTHONPATH' during creation.

Comment: Please define `PYTHONPATH` as mention by @jhyankysmith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As those modules are built-in, it seems that you have not defined the **Python interpreter** for your IDE and/or the **project's properties**.

Set your Python installation in `Project -> Properties -> Interpreter/Grammar`

In case you want to use external modules, you can add them to the project by defining the PYTHONPATH in `Project -> Properties -> PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Grammar Version: 2.7/Interpreter: Default -> Grammar Version: 3.0/Interpreter: Python (I guess?); the PYTHONPATH was indeed empty

Comment: Under "Interpreter" combobox you will find a link that says "Click here to configure an interpreter not listed" where you can select the path to your python installation.

Comment: Path already seems already to be correct (ref. Preferences). And contains all the builtins beneath Forced Builtins?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you say, anyway, you will find the installed modules in /lib/site-packages/ folder

Comment: I see (both in the Preferences/Python Interpreters & PyDev Package Explorer view) that the cv2.pyd is part of the System Libs, numpy.pyd is part of the Forced Builtins which both belong to my Pyhon33. But what I need to do with them?