# theano.config.floatX doesnt give any output

Tags: config, theano

print (theano.config.floatX) doesnt work.

my .theanorc is as below:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu0

[nvcc]
fastmath = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution at :[Python won't find variable in module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675274/python-wont-find-variable-in-module)

You have to go to the Python interpreter settings in Eclipse preferences and add theano.configdefaults to the list of built-ins