# Python NLTK multi threading

Tags: python, multithreading, lazy-loading, nltk

I am writing an algorithm which identifies sentences in given text, split each sentence into words & return these words after some validations.

I want to implement the same with the help of multi threading.

I'm calling my function which deals with each sentence in  `threading.thread()` for which it throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'WordListCorpusReader' object has no attribute '_LazyCorpusLoader__args'
```

However, there are few blogs which suggest to use "`wn.ensure_loaded()`" function.

But python throws an error saying `ensure_loaded()` is not defined.

Can someone help me solve this.

**EDIT:**

```
text = "This is my sample text. I want to break it into sentences"  
sentences=(re.split(r"(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s",text))  
wn.ensure_loaded()      
co = CoOccurence()     #CoOccurence is a class in my package which will work on the sentences  
for sentence in sentences:  
    t = Thread(target=co.__prepareHash__, args=(sentence,)) #co.__prepareHash__   is an other method which works around the sentences  
    threads.append(t)  
    t.start()  

flag =1  
while (flag):  
    flag = __isThreadAlive__()
```

This throws me an error: `Attribute error: 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute '_LazyCorpusLoader__args'`
When I try to check `wn.ensure_loaded()`, it throws `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ensure_loaded'`

with ref. to : [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433370/what-would-cause-wordnetcorpusreader-to-have-no-attribute-lazycorpusloader)

Thank You

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code context?

Comment: @lenz Added some code, hope it'll give you some context

Comment: First: why is the exception about the concept "dog"? I don't see anything related to "dog" in your testing text. Second: The solution in the linked SO post is "to access the `wn` object *before* you enter into your threading." It doesn't look like you are doing that.

Comment: kindly ignore the example of dog as it doesn't have any significance here. I'm using wn.ensure_loading() in the third line (edited) . Pl. check

Comment: How do you import/assign to the name `wn`? I think the exception caused by calling `wn.ensure_loaded()` might lead you to the root of the problem.

Comment: @lenz from  nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

Comment: can you please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077639/python-difference-in-pydev-python-idle
Because the same programming is executing very well from IDLE. Issue is when I run the same from eclipse PyDev

Comment: Oh well. It's hard to debug that from a distance. I can only suggest what you should check next: maybe the two interpreters use separate NLTK data directories (or even installations), and probably in one of them some (wordnet corpus?) data are missing, or the installed NLTK versions differ...