# Use nltk.corpus multithreaded

Tags: python, multithreading, nltk, wordnet

I would like to access [`nltk.corpus.wordnet`](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) in a multithreaded environment. As soon as I enable multithreading, methods such as `synsets()` fail. If I disable it, everything works fine.

The error messages change. For example, an error could look like this, which looks very much like a race condition to me:

```
File "/home/lhk/anaconda3/envs/dlab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 1342, in synset_from_pos_and_offset
    assert synset._offset == offset
```

There are other questions about this:

- The problem here was also caused by multithreading: [What would cause WordNetCorpusReader to have no attribute LazyCorpusLoader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433370/what-would-cause-wordnetcorpusreader-to-have-no-attribute-lazycorpusloader/27437149#27437149)
- This question has a more general title but seems to describe the same problem (multithreaded corpus loading fails): [Python NLTK multi threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076532/python-nltk-multi-threading)
- There is an issue about this: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1576

The solution to the first linked question was to load the corpus before your program branches up into individual threads. I've done that: `wordnet.ensure_loaded()` is called before the multithreading.

The recommendation in the GitHub issue is to import wordnet within my threaded function. But that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to make a deep copy of the corpus, for every thread. Of course this needs lots of memory and is not very efficient:

```
import copy
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
wn.ensure_loaded()

# at the beginning of the multi-threaded environment
my_wn = copy.deepcopy(wn)
```

Comment: This solution appears to generate `LookupError` for other corpus datasets that are not downloaded. I have not been able to make `deepcopy(wn)` work successfully in any case.

Comment: Were you guys able to find any working solution?