# WordNetLemmatizer on dask.dataframe errors with 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute '_LazyCorpusLoader__args'

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, python-3.6, dask

I am trying to do stemming on a dask dataframe

```py
wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()

def lemmatizing(sentence):
    stemSentence = ""

    for word in sentence.split():
        stem = wnl.lemmatize(word)
        stemSentence += stem
        stemSentence += " "

        stemSentence = stemSentence.strip()

    return stemSentence

df['news_content'] = df['news_content'].apply(stemming).compute()
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute '_LazyCorpusLoader__args'
```

I already tried what was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611148/multi-threading-in-nltk-wordnetlemmatizer), but without any luck.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `wordnet` module was "lazily read" and not evaluated yet.

One hack to make it work is to first use the `WordNetLemmatizer()` once before using it in the Dask dataframe, e.g.

```
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> import dask.dataframe as dd

>>> df = dd.read_csv('something.csv')
>>> df.head()
                      text  label
0       this is a sentence      1
1  that is a foo bar thing      0


>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> wnl.lemmatize('cats') # Use it once first, to "unlazify" wordnet.
'cat'

# Now you can use it with Dask dataframe's .apply() function.
>>> lemmatize_text = lambda sent: [wnl.lemmatize(word) for word in sent.split()]

>>> df['lemmas'] = df['text'].apply(lemmatize_text)
>>> df.head()
                      text  label                          lemmas
0       this is a sentence      1         [this, is, a, sentence]
1  that is a foo bar thing      0  [that, is, a, foo, bar, thing]
```

---

Alternatively, you can try `pywsd`:

```
pip install -U pywsd
```

Then in code:

```
>>> from pywsd.utils import lemmatize_sentence
Warming up PyWSD (takes ~10 secs)... took 9.131901025772095 secs.

>>> import dask.dataframe as dd

>>> df = dd.read_csv('something.csv')
>>> df.head()
                      text  label
0       this is a sentence      1
1  that is a foo bar thing      0

>>> df['lemmas'] = df['text'].apply(lemmatize_sentence)
>>> df.head()
                      text  label                          lemmas
0       this is a sentence      1         [this, be, a, sentence]
1  that is a foo bar thing      0  [that, be, a, foo, bar, thing]
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot.

Comment: Question, why does that workflow work and ```.compute()``` errors out?

Comment: It's because wordnet needs to be evaluated first. Unlike modern python libraries where most things are pre-evaluated. Many things works like generators in older times when machine resources are limited. So using the `WordNetLemmatizer()` once would have kicked the wordnet to be evaluated.

Comment: "Lazy loading" is a design pattern that's less talked about today because machines are bigger but it can be beneficial when machine resources are limited =) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading

Comment: Sidenote: if you are working in a jupyter notebook you have to make sure that you take your time in between executing the cell ```wnl.lemmatize('cats')``` and the rest. Otherwise, you will get the same error. If the code is in one cell add a sleep statement to wait 5 seconds or so.