# Python callbacks into the main module (functions and variables)

Tags: python

I am trying to have a module that provides a framework of sorts to short declarative one-file scripts that I write.  In the short scripts, I would like to define a number of variables and functions that are accessed or called back by the framework module.

I am stuck ... I have tried two approaches, and I am not crazy about either one.  Is there a better way?

**First approach:**

Framework module:

```
import __main__
def test():
    print __main__.var
    print __main__.func()
```

Script:

```
import framework
var="variable"
def func():
    print "function"
framework.test()
```

I like this approach and it works, but eclipse gives me an 'Undefined variable from import: var' error on any imported variable or function from main.  Obviously, this is not correct as it works, but it clutters up eclipse with many false errors.

**Second Approach:**

Framework module:

```
def test(glob):
    print glob['var']
    print glob['func']()
```

Script:

```
import framework
var="variable"
def func():
    print "function"
framework.test(globals())
```

This seems to work and does not give me errors, but I don't like the dictionary type notation used to call variables and functions ... especially for functions: func'funcName'.

Is there a better way to implement this that results in clean code?  Can I pass in a module name (ie **main**) as an argument to a function?  Can Eclipse errors on **main** for the first approach be turned off?

Comment: How about `def test(var, func):` in the module, and `framework.test(var, func)` in the script? Or is your example a simplification and your real code has lots of dependencies and it would be burdensome to pass a variable for each one?

Comment: Yap, this is an oversimplification ... there will be many variables and functions.

Comment: OT: glob is a bad variable name...

Comment: Using `__main__` seems a perfectly reasonable solution. For the Eclipse nonsense, see [how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112715/how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors).

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks! command+1 works great to ignore the undefined variable error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with the first approach and told Eclipse to ignore the **Undefined Variable from Import** error by pressing command+1 (for my Mac, for Windows it would be ctrl+1) on each line where this error occurred.

command+1 adds the following comment to the end of each line:

```
# @UndefinedVariable
```

Thanks to @ekhumoro for pointing this out in the comments.