# no member pylint errors on calls to cython

Tags: python, cython, pylint

Is there anyway to automatically whitelist modules with a specific name?

I am having issues with no member calls from cython and would like to auto whitelist. Pylint is failing to find member so at this point I want to name modules with a specific format and cyth_util and whitelist cython modules of that format.

Answer (score 1):

To specifically ignore no-member any time a module is used, put this into [your pylintrc](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#typecheck-checker)

```
[TYPECHECK]
inored-modules=cython
```

If you're using PyDev (through Eclipse), then I think this ticket has some help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2248987/910963