# PyGame not working in Eclipse using Python3.4

Tags: python, eclipse, pygame, ubuntu-14.04, pydev

I am using Linux Mint 17 (Ubuntu 14.04) and already got pygame 1.9.2 working in Eclipse on my Windows PC. Now I also installed it on this machine, but it doesn't work. Thus there is no apt-get for python3-pygame I downloaded the source from https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame and built and installed it without getting errors.

When running the following on the command line I receive no error:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
```

If I try the same in an Eclipse PyDev project I get the error: "Undefined variable from import: init".

First I thought that my Interpreter was not set up correctly, but the path where pygame is installed is added to the libraries (/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages). I realized that for Python2.7 pygame is installed in /usr/lib/pytho2.7/dist-packages instead, but this directory doesn't exist for python3.4 on my machine.

Since it seems to work on the command-line it must have something to do with the Eclipse or Pydev settings, right?

UPDATE:
Ok, now things are getting really confusing. I found out that pygame indeed is also working from within eclipse if I run the project, but only giving me these error messages for eg. pygame.init(), pygame.QUIT, pygame.K_ESCAPE, pygame.KEYDOWN. I find it very strange, because pygame.time.Clock() or pygame.display.set_caption() don't give error messages. So I only get undefined variable from import errors (also see here [How do I fix PyDev "Undefined variable from import" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112715/how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors) ).

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo pip3 install pygame`, pip3 should work assuming you have python3 and setuptools installed.

You can install pip3 using `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and then use `sudo pip3 install package_name` to get whatever you want.

Comment: Seems like a good idea in the first place.. Would have made it way easier for me to install it.. Nevertheless it returns: "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pygame in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Cleaning up..."

Comment: You could use `sudo pip3 uninstall pygame` to remove the existing install and then reinstall it. Should stabilize everything.

Comment: Mhh, it seems that pip3 also doesn't have the pygame package: "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pygame".. I was building it myself only, because pip also doesn't support a python3 pygame build.

Comment: I uninstalled it now and reinstalled it using sudo pip3 install hg+https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame. Unfortunately this doesn't work aswell.. I also think that it is an issue with Eclipse, since it is working well using the python command line...

Comment: I am one step further.. It is probably a PyDev error.. There are a lot of threads around, but still didn't find a solution...

Answer (score 1):

The only thing which worked for me (I spent two days now finding out what the problem is) is to add "pygame" to the forced builtins for the Interpreter (Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter -> Python Interpreter -> Forced Builtins Tab -> New -> *pygame*.

This is only a workaround, but at least I am rid of those errors for now and auto-completion still works. I didn't find any other solution that worked for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was resolved by importing `*`.
instead of:

```
import pygame
```

try this:

```
from  pygame import *
```

now instead of calling `init()` by saying `pygame.init()` just use `init()`
also you should not have to explicitly call using `pygame.` for the most part.

NOTE: after playing around with this in Eclipse I did end up having to use both:

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
```

for whatever reason one of my functions only works if I have `pygame.even.get()`
but the test of my code does not need to use `pygame.`
(I am sure there is a perfectly good reason but I am still very new to python)