# Pydev setup not recognizing undefined value

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, python-3.4

I have PyDev setup in eclipse.I think I did everything to configure my workspace to show python files in PyDev perspective. It still does not show the files in Python format.

Steps tried

- installed PyDev in eclipse,
- Configured PythonPATH
- Associated file types.
- Opened in PyDev perspective.
- Closed and opened the project.

Still the files show in normal Text format..not in the python format.

Answer (score 0):

After too many trials , I was able to get to something--
- I changed the PyDev-> Code Analysis -> Undefined to warning 
- same with Imports as per in this link --[How do I fix PyDev "Undefined variable from import" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112715/how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors/2248987#2248987)

-I stopped and started eclipse again.

These steps took care of the issue.
Hope it helps for anyone stuck like this.